# TypeScript, what is the correct way to use 'import'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm playing with Angular 2.0 / TypeScript (Visual Studio 2015, TS 1.6), and I'm trying to understand how the 'import from' is supposed to work.
I have defined my module in app.ts with the output path set to ./build.

In bootstrap.ts I import the module with

```
import {bootstrap} from "angular2/angular2";
import {App} from "./app";
bootstrap(App);
```

Since I have the build destination different than the source destination, the only way I can get this working is to add each file to System.Config()

```
<script>
    System.config({
        packages: {
            './build/bootstrap': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
            './build/app': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
            './build/Components/Comp01/component': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
            './build/Components/Comp02/component': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        },
    });
    System.import('./build/bootstrap');
</script>
```

If I change the import statement to use from './build/app.js' then I get a TS2307 error, 'cannot find module ./build.app.js'
If I change the import statement to './app.ts' then the compiler is happy, but obviously the browser then attempts to load app.ts rather than app.js

What is the correct way to use 'import' in TypeScript when the output is at different location ?

Comment: The way you are doing this looks right to me, although I used `map` in my System config. What is the problem? Is the TypeScript compiler complaining?

Comment: As I mentioned, when I add the individual files  to system.config and set the defaultExtension then it works. But I fail to see the benefit of using System.import, if I still have to add each and every file to a config section, and I have to add the default extension = js. I expected system.import to be smart enough to load the dependencies automatically, after all they are already defined in the .import statement in the dependent file. That is the reason I thought I was not configuring system.config correct

Answer (score 0):

There is one way for this as i know ::

You should do a trick like this.

suppose you have a folder app and there are two files in this folder app.ts and bootstrap.ts

so you should make your js folder structure same like the ts folder structure E.g your build folder will have two files app.js bootstrap.js

then with the following code

```
import {App} from "./app";
```

**there will be no error because loader will find app.js with the above specified path and import will find the app.ts with the same specified path.**

And suppose you have another folder in app folder named component1 and there is a component1.ts file

Then You should make your js folder structure same as the ts folder so build will have component1 folder and component1 folder will have component1.js

so supoose you have to import app.ts in component1.ts then

```
 import {App} from "../app";
```

it will find js and ts both with the same path

Comment: Thats exactly what I have, and without the import.config section I get a 404 on the bootstrap file as it attempts to load 'bootstrap', not 'bootstrap.js'.

I tried to remove the build folder and have the js files in the same folder as the ts file, and still the browser attempts to load only 'filename', not 'filename.js'